# Input Text, Image and button stuck at the top left corner

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm just new to kotlin and now trying to design the profile page just like the image below in android studio.

[image]

When I am designing the profile page, I realize that the design in the application is display correctly. So, I run the project in a phone simulator and then everything stuck on the top left corner. After that, I trying to add a relative layout but  the result still the same. May I know which part I do wrong or is there any solution?

[image]

Below is the coding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/white">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="141dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="98dp"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/first_name"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="265dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName3"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/last_name"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="220dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="265dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress"
    android:layout_width="379dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:text="@string/email"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="333dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
    android:layout_width="379dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/password"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="407dp"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
    <!--android:inputType="textPassword"-->

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword2"
    android:layout_width="379dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/confirm_password"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="479dp"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
    <!--android:inputType="textPassword"-->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="378dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:text="@string/save"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="556dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/first_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName3"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/last_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword2"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:hint="@string/confirm_password"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! its work!! Is it because I didn't set the constraint? And do you have any suggested website or video for me to learn it ? It is very useful for me and much appreciate it.

Comment: @fallenhamster https://stackoverflow.com/a/71363781/11439327

Answer (score 2):

The way a `ConstraintLayout` works is you define the position and size of your views using *constraints* - things like "aligned with the left edge of the parent", "below this `ImageView` with a margin of 16dp", "fill the space between these two views, but maintain a 16:9 aspect ratio" etc.

You've got three issues here:

- you're using a `ConstraintLayout` but you haven't set any constraints, and you've suppressed the errors warning you about that with `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"`
- all your stuff is nested inside a `RelativeLayout` so it wouldn't use the constraints anyway, and the `ConstraintLayout` is useless
- you're using absolute positioning inside the `RelativeLayout` (`absoluteX` and all that) **but you're using the `tools` prefix** which is for defining stuff that shows up at design time **but not when the app is running** - it's used for testing, placeholder text etc. Also `layout_editor_absoluteX` **is a special attribute that only works in the layout editor** - it's like a positioning hack for while you're designing. Doesn't affect anything while the app is running.

So the result is none of your views actually have any positioning attributes set on them, and they all just end up in the top left corner, at the origin

You should probably ditch the `RelativeLayout` approach and l[earn to use `ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) (which it sounds like you wanted anyway) - it's way more flexible and you're going to run into it/need it at some point

Comment: Your answer is very helpful for me to know my mistake, thanks for the detailed explanation !

Comment: @fallenhamster no worries! If you use ConstraintLayout, you can just use the layout editor to arrange your views. It's a nice way to learn what it can do

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the "RelativeLayout" Tag. Learn more about "ConstraintLayout" from here. https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Comment: I have tried to run the project in the phone simulator without RelativeLayout, but the results still the same, everything is stuck on the left top corner.

Answer (score 0):

Copying an answer from here won't help, it gonna make you struggle with your next layout, instead I recommend you to take a look on:

- [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)
- [Relative Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative)
- [Linear Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear)